# Finding the most frequently occurring sequence using T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sequence, sybase, frequency-analysis

I generate a table that looks something like this given some input value:

```
COL1   COL2   COL3
x      1      A
.      .      .
.      .      .
.      .      .
x      n      B
y      1      A
.      .      .
.      .      .
.      .      .
y      n      S
z      1      A
.      .      .
.      .      .
.      .      .
z      n      B
```

`COL1` and `COL2` are `numeric` datatypes and `COL3` is a `varchar` of non-constant length per row.

What I want to do is to find the most frequently occurring sequence. Each time I generate the table, the number of sequences, and the sequence length can be different (note that the length of the sequences within a generated table is constant). `x`, `y` and `z` are random numbers. So in the above case I'd like to end up with:

```
A
.
.
.
B
```

Any ideas? :)

Comment: `x1A` and `znB` are possible sequences?

Comment: Yes, the values of `COL3` are basically words of different lengths.

Comment: So if the length of the sequence happens to be 3, a sequence might be `Hello`, `sky`, `very nice`.

Comment: I suggest you use real table and columns names and real data in your examples. I fear that you have abstracted too far and this description is like a chapter from wonderland. Why are you "generating the table" frequently? and what the heck does this mean: `note that the length of the sequences within a generated table is constant` if the length is constant how does this happen: `the sequence length can be different`? Is there one table or many tables? Please re-consider how you have portrayed your problem.

Comment: It means that once the table is generated, each sequence has the same length `n` as shown above. However, the next time a table is generated, `n` is not necessarily the same as before. I understand that "the sequence length can be different" makes no sense to you when you take it out of its context... And I'm afraid I won't address your concerns about abstraction levels and Wonderland chapters; I don't want to provide a specific table because (1) it adds nothing new, and, (2) it might lead to answers that are specific to the table in the example, which is not at all what I am looking for.

Comment: How does your code expect to know what n is every time the table is created? Why also are you storing words in single letter values in a column spanning across rows because you're going to use a lot of IO reading lots of rows for single letter values rather than using a word per row i.e. the better format to manage it as actual data.

Sometimes the smallest storage method is not optimal for retrieval.